# how to dynamic set cookie value in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter test plan structure

Test Plan

```
Test Thread

    Cookie Manager(set variable PHPSessionID)

    HTTP request A

    regular expression extractor(get value from HTTP A's response, set PHPSessionID value)

    HTTP request B(I want PHPSessionID send by B request as a cookie value )
```

As we know Config controller is execute before A request, so it won't reset PHPSessionID value in Cookie. Is there any method to do what I want? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookie information is dynamic for each thread, so I think it already does what you want:

> If you have an HTTP Request and the response contains a cookie, the
>   Cookie Manager automatically stores that cookie and will use it for
>   all future requests to that particular web site. Each JMeter thread
>   has its own "cookie storage area". So, if you are testing a web site
>   that uses a cookie for storing session information, each JMeter thread
>   will have its own session. Note that such cookies do not appear on the
>   Cookie Manager display, but they can be seen using the View Results
>   Tree Listener.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager

Comment: Thank you for your help, BlackGaff! 
I change cookie policy to "compatibility" in cookie manager, then I saw PHPSessionID is recorded automatic, it partly solve my problem .

I want to dynamic set cookie value for another reason. I am testing a webgame, which have a accountID, in each http request need to send this accountID's MD5 value in cookie.
so for accountID 100001, which send in cookie is E2A6A1ACE352668000AED191A817D143, I can use a program in pre shell bean to caculate it. but how can I set this value in cookie